# SharePoint 2013 Custom Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I am trying to customize search result through display template. I am customizing "**Item_CommonItem_Body.html**" file to include custom managed property in the place of title I am trying to put custom managed property

I created one variable

```
var xxx_subject = ctx.CurrentItem.DocSubjectXXX;
```

using same in

```
var titleHtml = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" id="{1}" style="cursor: pointer;" class="ms-srch-item-link" title="{3}" onfocus="{4}" {5}>{6}</a>',
                                      $htmlEncode(clickType), $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.titleLink), $urlHtmlEncode(url), $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title), 
                                      showHoverPanelCallback, appAttribs, xxx_subject);
```

But I am always getting empty value. But at the same time when I try to see with **SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool v2.1** I get the data.
[image]

So I don't know what I am doing mistake !!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the managed property mapping in the display template?  Look for the tag starting with `<mso:ManagedPropertyMaping` in the head of the template.  You need to add a mapping to your managed property.  It should be in the following format:

```
'<current item property name>':'<managed property name>'
```

Yours should be like this:

```
'DocSubjectXXX':'DocSubjectXXX' // Managed properties are comma separated.
```

You can find more details [here](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/).

Comment: You hit the correct nail But I already did it and still it is showing blank :(

Comment: Other than making sure the list/library has been crawled, and that the managed property has been mapped to a crawled property, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well I did Full Crawl + Incremental Crawl 4 to 5 time